# Error ORA-00936: I dont know how to use a sequence number in this solution

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I run the code below in oracle developer, I get error

> `ORA-00936: missing expression . CREATE TABLE table_prc4 ( name VARCHAR2(20) );`
> this code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmembe (
    str IN VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_prc4 VALUES (
        SELECT
            regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS parts 
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
            regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL 
    );
commit;
END ;

BEGIN
    addnewmembe('saeed,amir,hossein');
END;
```

I want to show in the result in the row sequence number and a name of the input string

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Change `INSERT INTO table_prc4 VALUES (SELECT ...)` to `INSERT INTO table_prc4 SELECT ...`

Comment: i can try , then i tell you the result . very very thank you for your helping with me friends.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. Bohemian has told you above what was wrong with your query, and your new request still contains the same invalid syntax.